# How to design text view in android without layout use only java class code

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am designing an android application where I have not need to create any layout xml file, but create over the Java code itself. I try with this way:-

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    TextView tb;    

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ch);

    } 
}
```

Comment: Make one class extends with TextView and call that class by setContentVIew(new YourClassName(this));

Comment: when you call this no need to layout file.

Comment: Piyansh ..There is also need For Xml Layout or XML File i m not want to use xml file

Comment: not good code please check down side code that are currect for this case. ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code, this will work for you

```
public class Amit extends Activity{
TextView tb;    

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ch);
       tb = new TextView(Amit.this);

    tb.setText("hallo hallo");
    tb.setId(5);
    tb.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
setContentView(tb);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use TextView like this :**

```
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
     ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

     TextView tv = new TextView(this);
     tv.setText("Here is your textview");
     ll.addView(tv);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setText("HELLO");
    ll.addView(tv1);


    setContentView(ll);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Creating a new RelativeLayout
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        // Defining the RelativeLayout layout parameters.
        // In this case I want to fill its parent
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        // Creating a new TextView
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Test");

        // Defining the layout parameters of the TextView
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

        // Setting the parameters on the TextView
        tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

        // Adding the TextView to the RelativeLayout as a child
        relativeLayout.addView(tv);

        // Setting the RelativeLayout as our content view
        setContentView(relativeLayout, rlp);
    }
}
```

Comment: comp-lacy to do a little bit of work.....u have designe many of lines for small problem ....not good code

Comment: @amitsharma But sure its a working code and feels lengthy because of those comments..

Comment: u should understand a think in it industry less comp-lacy and work should dun in very less time and line of code are increase..... if there i can understend ur code is currect bt in indudtry there is no need ......so check currect answer....k Man.....user3181047...